# Flutter, calculated Double do not work for circularprogress bar

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, double, progress-bar

I want to calculate the Percentage for the different Circularprogressbars with data from my Firestore Database. But when i use the calculated Doubles instead of hardcoded doubles i get this error and i can not explain my self why iam getting this error in the Terminal:
|
The getter 'weekActivity' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: weekActivity
|
Can someone help me to fix this error?

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6D3h.png)

```
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_circular_chart/flutter_circular_chart.dart';
import 'package:testapp/models/Goals.dart';
import 'package:testapp/services/Services.dart';

class ReadingPage extends StatefulWidget {
final Goal goal;

const ReadingPage({Key key, this.goal}) : super(key: key);

@override
_ReadingPageState createState() => _ReadingPageState();
}

class _ReadingPageState extends State<ReadingPage> {

int _currentValue = 1;

//weeklyGoals
bool weekActivityFinished = false;
bool weekReadTimeFinished = false;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 final _chartSize = const Size(145, 145);

 return Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
    appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(35),
child: AppBar(
title: Align(
alignment: Alignment.center,
child: Text('Reading', style: TextStyle(
fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
color: Colors.grey[900],
fontSize: 25,
decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
decorationColor: Color(0XFF006699),
decorationThickness: 1.5,
),),
),
backgroundColor: Colors.white,
),
),
body: Container(
margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
height: 260.0,
child: StreamBuilder(
stream: FirestoreService().getGoals(),
builder: (BuildContext context,
AsyncSnapshot<List<Goal>> snapshot) {
if (snapshot.hasError || !snapshot.hasData)
return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(
backgroundColor: Color(0XFF1954A1),
));
return SizedBox(
height: 250,
child: ListView.builder(
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
itemCount: 1,
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
Goal goal = snapshot.data[index];
return Row(
children: <Widget>[
Container(
padding: EdgeInsets.only(
top: 5, bottom: 10, left: 30, right: 30),
child: Container(
width: 330.0,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
color: Colors.white,
borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),boxShadow: [
BoxShadow(
color: Colors.grey[500],
offset: const Offset(0.5, 1),
blurRadius: 5.0,
spreadRadius: 0.1,
),
]),
child: Column(
children: <Widget>[
Row(
children: <Widget>[
Container(
padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
width: 240,
child: Align(
alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
child: Container(
child: Text(
'WeeklyGoals', style: TextStyle(
fontSize: 25,
),),
),
),
),
Align(
alignment: Alignment.topRight,
child: Container(
padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5,right: 0, left: 0,
bottom: 0),
child: FlatButton(
child: Text('edit', style: TextStyle(
fontSize: 16,
color: Colors.yellow[700]
),),
onPressed: () {}
)
),
)
],
),
Row(
children: <Widget>[
Container(
width: 160,
margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
child: Column(
children: <Widget>[
Text('Activity', style: TextStyle(
fontSize: 18
),),
Center(
child: new AnimatedCircularChart(
size: _chartSize,
initialChartData: <
CircularStackEntry>[
new CircularStackEntry(
<CircularSegmentEntry>[
new CircularSegmentEntry(
_weekActivityProgress(),
weekActivityFinished
? Colors
    .yellow[700]
    : Color(
0XFF006699),
rankKey: 'completed',
),
new CircularSegmentEntry(
100,
Colors.grey[300],
rankKey: 'remaining',
),
],
rankKey: 'progress',
),
],
chartType: CircularChartType
    .Radial,
percentageValues: true,
holeLabel: '${goal
    .weekActivity != null
? goal.weekActivity
    : '-'}/${goal
    .weekActivityGoal != null
? goal.weekActivityGoal
    : '-'}',
labelStyle: new TextStyle(
color: Colors.blueGrey[600],
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
fontSize: 24.0,
),
),
),
],
),
),
Container(
width: 160,
child: Column(
children: <Widget>[
Text('Time', style: TextStyle(
fontSize: 18
),),
Center(
child: new AnimatedCircularChart(
size: _chartSize,
initialChartData: <
CircularStackEntry>[
new CircularStackEntry(
<CircularSegmentEntry>[
new CircularSegmentEntry(
_weekReadingProgress(),
weekReadTimeFinished
? Colors
    .yellow[700]
    : Color(
0XFF006699),
rankKey: 'completed',
),
new CircularSegmentEntry(
100,
Colors.grey[300],
rankKey: 'remaining',
),
],
rankKey: 'progress',
),
],
chartType: CircularChartType
    .Radial,
percentageValues: true,
holeLabel: '${goal
    .weekReadTime != null
? goal.weekReadTime
    .toStringAsFixed(2)
    : '-'} / ${goal
    .weekReadTimeGoal != null
? goal.weekReadTimeGoal
    : '-'}',
labelStyle: new TextStyle(
color: Colors.blueGrey[600],
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
fontSize: 24.0,
),
),
),
],
),
),
],
),
],
),
),
),
]);
}),
);
})));
}

//week
double _weekReadingProgress(){
var _weekReadingProgress = widget.goal.weekReadTime != null? widget.goal.weekReadTimeGoal : 0 *100 ~/ 
widget.goal.weekReadTimeGoal;
if(widget.goal.weekReadTime.toInt() >= widget.goal.weekReadTimeGoal){
setState(() {
weekReadTimeFinished = true;
});}
return _weekReadingProgress.toDouble();
}

double _weekActivityProgress(){
var _weekActivityProgress = widget.goal.weekActivity != null? widget.goal.weekActivity : 0 *100 ~/ 
widget.goal.weekActivityGoal;
if(widget.goal.weekActivity >= widget.goal.weekActivityGoal){
setState(() {
weekReadTimeFinished = true;
});}
return _weekActivityProgress.toDouble();
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `goal` is null at one of places where you use `goal.weekActivity`.

At all places where you use `goal.weekActivity`, first ensure `goal != null`. Since it comes from Firestore, it's possible that there are no goals in the database when this error occurs. If you try this and find that it is always null, you should make sure it exists in the database.

Comment: i changed goal.weekActivity != null? to goal != null. But i still get the problem and  in Firebase there are data.

Comment: i get the error when i add _weekActivtyProgress() instead of a double like "double Double = 0.01" as aProgress indicator for the progressbar.